Problem to find 32768 Hz crystal with 0.1 pF of Cshunt
Following the SAMD21 datasheet, I found the following table for choosing the correct crystal for the external oscillator.

As you can see, the CSHUNT value given is about 0.1 pF, which I'm not able to find. I have found the following crystal: SC32S-7PF20PPM. Where all the other values match in range except for the CSHUNT which is 1.0 pF NOT 0.1 pF. I'm starting to think that there is an error on the datasheet... Can someone more specialized help me to find a correct crystal or tell me if the datasheet is wrong?

That table is not the requirements for the external crystal. It is describing the characteristics of the oscillator circuit on the chip.

This specification indicates that there is 0.1 pF of shunt capacitance internal to the microcontroller's oscillator circuit. For precision applications, this needs to be taken into consideration to determine the exact frequency of oscillation. For similar reasons, the crystal itself will have a rated shunt capacitance.
There is no need for the crystal's shunt capacitance to match, or for it not to match, the oscillator's shunt capacitance. The only specifications here that dictates anything about the external crystal are the maximum load capacitance of 12.5 pF and maximum ESR of 100 kΩ; you need to use a crystal with a rated load capacitance and ESR less than these.
The other information here is intended to help you bias your crystal properly. If you want to meet the crystal's full rated accuracy, you need to consider the parasitic load capacitance presented by the microcontroller (given as 3.2 pF typical on the XIN32 pin and 3.7 pF on XOUT32) when determining what external load capacitors to use; just subtract these from the nominal capacitance. You also need to subtract any parasitic capacitance in the traces on the board, which should be less than a pF if laid out properly--you can find crystal layout recommendations elsewhere on this site or others, so I won't go into details here.
